# why is the switch case not breaking after the first if case is printed?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, case

in the below if statement if it's false it would print the else statement correctly. `"No order with this number exists, please create a new order."` and if it's true it prints the first statement correctly as well, but it's always followed by the `else` statement. Why isn't the `break;` terminating after the first if case is printed?

```
case(3):{ 
              System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Please Enter The Order Number: ");
            int orderno = input.nextInt();
            Iterator<Order> orderIterator3 = orders.getIterator();
            Order currentorder;
            String itemRemoved = null;
            StackInterface <String> newItems = new ArrayStack<String>();
            while ( orderIterator3.hasNext()) { //iterate through the list until an order  with a matching order no is found 
                currentorder = orderIterator3.next();  
            if(currentorder.getNumber() == orderno) { //access the Items in the list by their order number 
                newItems = currentorder.getItems(); //Copy the existing items into a new stack
                if (!newItems.isEmpty())
                itemRemoved = newItems.pop();
                 System.out.println("The last item: " + itemRemoved + "\n was successfully removed from your order!"); break;
                }//End if

            }//End While 
            System.out.println("No order with this number exists, please create a new order."); break;
          }// End Case 3
```

Comment: Because you have no `break` statement.

Comment: It breaks the enclosing while(), and therefore fails to break the switch.

Comment: `System.out.println("The last item: " + itemRemoved + "\n was successfully removed from your order!"); break; `  <  I do

Comment: Please format your code so it's _legible_.

Comment: So where do I have to put the break then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you break inside the `while-loop`, you will break the `while-loop`, not the `case`.

There are a few different ways of making this work, but the easiest would probably be to just add a boolean value that you set to true if it should break out of the case, something like:

```
boolean shouldBreak = false;
while( ... ) {
  if( ... ) {
    shouldBreak = true;
    break; // break out of the while.
  }
}
if(shouldBreak) {
  break; // break out of the switch/case.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not break a case from inside a while() loop. The most straightforward fix is to set a boolean to true when breaking the while, check it after the loop, and break again if true.